# Using the pumping theorem to show that this language is not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

Let $\sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ and let $L = \{s | s = a^jb^jc^k\}$ where $k=i\cdot j$ and $i,j \geq 0\}$. Using the pumping theorem, prove that $L$ is not context-free.

I really don't know where to start, here. Nobody in the class knows what to do and we're all failing pre-curve.

Comment: Where is $i$? Do you mean $a^ib^jc^k$?

Comment: @xskxzr Yeah, that has to be a typo. Taken literally, the language in the question as currently written actually _is_ context-free.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $L$ is context-free. Then the pumping lemma for context-free languages tells us that $L$ has a pumping length $p \ge 1$. We want to show that this leads to a contradiction, by exhibiting a string that is in $L$ but cannot be pumped in the manner specified in the lemma.

Consider the string $s = a^pb^pc^{(p^2)}$. Clearly, $s \in L$.

Now, see if you can show that all the possible ways of breaking down this string into the chunks specified in the lemma lead to a pumped string that is *not* in $L$.